# Getting error when trying to install SSL certificate to secure site

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, tomcat8, zerossl

Our team tried to install the SSL certificate provided by ZeroSSL on mapblazer.com and got errors shown below towards the bottom. I have shared the Apache error log below that includes all necessary information about server version, parameters etc. This is on an AWS instance without a dedicated IP address. Thank you

```
`29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.032 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.59
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.040 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Oct 6 2020 16:57:18 UTC
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.59.0
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows Server 2016
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\logging.properties
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: abort
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [2.0.5] using APR version [1.7.4].
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.064 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 3.0.10 1 Aug 2023]
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.368 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.567 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.598 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.configureUpgradeProtocol The ["https-openssl-apr-443"] connector has been configured to support negotiation to [h2] via ALPN
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.598 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-apr-443"]
29-Aug-2023 20:16:18.598 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-443]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:848)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)`
```

Expected to install the SSL certificate on the Tomcat server without any errors.